# Two thirds histogram Ruby

Tags: ruby, histogram

I want put tab1 on the Thread

```
a = [0,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,9,9,10]
tab1 = Hash[*a.group_by{ |v| v }.flat_map{ |k, v| [k, v.size] }]
puts t1=Thread.new{tab1}
puts t2=Thread.new{tab1}
t1.join
t2.join
```

Comment: You may want to try cleaning up the question a bit. You've used "third", "theard", and "Thread" here; are they all intended to be the same thing? It's also a little unclear what you're asking. I would suggest adding comments to your code sample to show what you're trying to do with each line.

Comment: I changed the question

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. This?

```
a = [0,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,9,9,10]
tab1 = proc { Hash[a.group_by{ |v| v }.map{ |k, v| [k, v.size] }] }
t1 = Thread.new(&tab1)
t2 = Thread.new(&tab1)
p t1.value
p t2.value
```